# How to bind 3 keys at once to an event?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create shortcuts for my program.

I can bind 1 or 2 keys at once to an event, for example

```
self.rootwindow.bind("<Control-s>", lambda event: self.savefile())
```

but i can't seem to do the same for 3 keys, say, for example

```
self.rootwindow.bind("<Control-Shift_L-s>", lambda event: self.savefileas())
```

Any way to make it work like so? Or is there anyway to make it so I can bind 3 keys to an event like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Tkinter, `Control-R` means `Ctrl-Shift-R` and `Control-r` means `Ctrl-R`. So make sure you're not mixing up uppercase and lowercase.

Maybe you should try `Control-S`:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import Button, Frame, Tk    # Python 2

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
       frame = Frame(master)
       frame.pack()

       self.button = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.func)
       self.button.pack(side='left')

       master.bind('<Control-s>', self.save)
       master.bind('<Control-S>', self.exit)


    def save(self, _event=None):
        print("save the file")

    def exit(self, _event=None):
        print("exit")
        sys.exit()

root = Tk()
abc = MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```